# How can i add reference of Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms 8.0.0.0 in visual studio 2012?

Tags: asp.net, reportingservices-2005

I have reports deployed in SSRS 2005 and i want to integrate with asp.net applications.
But there is no option to add reference of Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms 8.0.0.0.

Does anyone knows how can i do that?

Comment: Inside Solution Explorer view, right click on your project and select "Add Reference" and then check under .NET tab. There is one as i can see in my Visual Studio version.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2012 Ultimate. I do not see this option

Comment: I have installed Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2005 SP1. how  can i use it with visual studio 2012?

Answer (score 0):

You may add the reference manually in the Project File (.csproj). Add this line in the  section.

```
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```